# How to send custom header information with forgot password url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I've created a custom link in laravel for forgot password that will be mailed to the user as he clicks on forgot password. Now, I want to add my custom header like timestamp to validate the url I have created so that if someone alters the url then user will not able to reset their password how it is possible? I have done this much.

```
public function forgotPassword(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        array(
            'email' => $request->emailId
        ),
        array(
            'email' => 'required|email'
        )
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        if ($errors->first('email')) {
            $message = $errors->first('email');
        } else {
            $message = __('apiMessages.parametersRequired');
        }
        $this->setMeta("422", $message);
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    try {
        $validateUser = User::where(array(
            'email' => $request->emailId,
            'userStatus' => Constant::STATUS_1))
            ->first();
        if (!$validateUser) {
            $this->setMeta('403', __('apiMessages.invalidEmailAddress'));
            return response()->json($this->setResponse());
        }
        $now = trim(Carbon::now()->timestamp);
        $userId = $validateUser->userId;
        $tokenUserId = '';
        $timestampToken = '';
        $alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_";
        while ($userId > 0) {
            $index = $userId % 64;
            $userId = ($userId - $index) / 64;
            $tokenUserId = $alphabet{$index} . $tokenUserId;
        }
        while ($now > 0) {
            $index = $now % 64;
            $now = ($now - $index) / 64;
            $timestampToken = $alphabet{$index} . $timestampToken;
        }
        $token = $tokenUserId . '$' . $timestampToken;

        $url = url('/') . '/api/resetPassword/' . $token;
        $link = '<a href="' . $url . '"> Link </a>';

        $name= $validateUser->firstName .' '.$validateUser->lastName;
        $subject = "Forgot Password";
        $msg = "Please go to this link and reset your password : " . $url;

        //$this->send($request->emailId, $name, $subject, $msg);
        $mailData = array(
            'to' => $request->emailId,
            'name' => $name,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'msg' => $msg
        );
        dispatch(new SendEmail($mailData));

        $this->setMeta("200", __('apiMessages.forgotPasswordEmail'));
        /*$this->setMeta("200", $link);
        $this->setData("timestamp", $now1);*/
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        $this->setMeta("500", __('apiMessages.queryError'));
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You cannot. It's not possible to add headers to an url, you can only send query string variables.

Comment: then how can we validate a url if someone alters it after open it?

Comment: The token that is provided in the url should be enough to make sure the user cannot generate these urls. If you wanted to, you could let the tokens expire in your database after a certain period of time.